# while calculating factorial in c why doesn't operation keep continuing further to negative values?

Tags: c, recursion, factorial

i was writing a recursion program for finding factorials , once x reaches zero why does the operation stop in the called function instead of continuing further to negative values like going -1,-2,-3 and so on as int takes negative values too and keep continuing the operation as it is my own user defined function.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
int factorial( int x);
int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    n=factorial(n);
    printf("%d",n);

    return 0;
}
int factorial(int x){
    int f;
    if(x==0||x==1){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
    f= x*factorial(x-1);
    return f;}
}
```

Comment: *once x reaches zero why does the operation stop in the called function*??  What do you think `if(x==0||x==1){
        return 1;
    }` does?

Comment: i think it returns value 1 to the calling function which value when it reaches 1 or 0 is something like if f=x*factorial(x-1)*(x-1)factorial(x-2).....1.factorial(x-(x-1))factorial(x-x) after calculation . i think it replaces factorial (x-x) and factorial(x-(x-1)) values as 1. my guess.

Comment: @Yemef ` keep continuing the operation as it is my own user defined function`. Hmm code says otherwise.

Comment: @SparKot can you explain? , i am new to c . so got no clue.

Comment: If you call with 0, what will it do?

Comment: Did you write this code or copied it from somewhere? If you did on your own, why did you add this condition? `if (x==0||x==1) { return 1; }`.

Comment: @SparKot since factorial  of both 1 and o are same i.e 1 . i used that condition. i wrote it.

Comment: @stark i mean if it was a main function i guess it would have returned true i.e success. but since it is a user defined functtion which i started studying only today in functions chapter , i guess it replaces value 0 in the mathematical function? no?

Comment: A "user-defined function" is a function defined by the user that is *supplied to a library or OS function*, such as a callback function. For example to `qsort()`. Here, it is just a function.

Comment: @WeatherVane okay? and here the userdefined function i made is int factorial( int x) . didn't answer my question though.

Comment: The function does not return success. It returns int.

Comment: It's been already answered by pointing out that the recursion terminates before `x` becomes negative. And it *isn't* a user defined function, which has a particular meaning.

Comment: @WeatherVane so by returning 1 , it terminates the program?

Comment: No, that's the result of the factorial calculation. It is the recursion that is terminated, not the program.

Comment: @WeatherVane got it. but why though , why does using return 1 , terminate the recursion. i am confused . i thought it just places whatever value is given to the calling function.

Comment: When `x > 1` the `factorial` function will call itself, that is *recurse*. But instead, it returns `1` to the previous caller. That is why it terminates: it no longer keeps calling itself. But it doesn't just terminate, it drops back through the stack of recursive calls that were made.

Comment: @WeatherVane i got it. my brain was in a loop . now that i understood , man it's so simple. it just went out of my head. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `factorial` is called with an argument value of 2, it evaluates `x==0||x==1` in the `if` statement. This condition is false, so the “then” clause in the `if` is not executed, and program control flows to the `else`.

The `else` executes `f = x*factorial(x-1)`, in which `x` is 2 and `factorial(x-1)` is `factorial(1)`.

Thus we have a recursive call to `factorial` with an argument value of 1. It evaluates `x==0||x==1` in the `if` statement. This condition is true, so the “then” clause is executed.

The “then” clause is `return 1;`, so the function returns 1, and program control returns to the caller.

In the caller, we are still evaluating `x*factorial(x-1)`. `factorial(x-1)` has returned 1, so we have `2*1`. So `f` is set to 2.

The next statement is `return f;`. So 2 is returned to the caller, and program control returns to the caller, which is `main`. The program continues executing `main`.

The program does not continue further to negative values because nothing called `factorial` with negative values.